# @font-face somehow not working

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-face

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but following this tutorial http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/ I, however, have problems getting it to work.

My code at top of style.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'chunkfiveregular';
    src: url('http://careerteam.de/wp-content/themes/theme1383/css/chunkfive-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://careerteam.de/wp-content/themes/theme1383/css/chunkfive-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://careerteam.de/wp-content/themes/theme1383/css/chunkfive-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://careerteam.de/wp-content/themes/theme1383/css/chunkfive-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://careerteam.de/wp-content/themes/theme1383/css/chunkfive-webfont.svg#chunkfiveregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I've got all the files in my root folder.

I later call the font-family via:

```
#man_translated {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-family:chunkfiveregular;
}
```

I'm in wordpress and the template I'm using has a preset font-canvas style for h1,h2,h3, converting each word to a png of font dakota handwritten. Perhaps this core setting within the template is in conflict with my onthefly javascript id/css change.

Comment: Just to be sure without having seen any HTML: Do you really have some HTML element(s) with a class attribute value of `p` or did you mean to select `<p>` elements instead?

Comment: Insufficient data. No way to reproduce the problem with this data – source of font not specified, browser(s) tested not identified. And the code contains a simple syntax error that can easily be detected using CSS Validator. A comment says “all checked”, but the syntax error still prevails in the question.

Comment: okay i should better edit my question, but nonetheless I can assure you that the code syntax is correct by now, but still its not working at all

Comment: I guess you template uses cufon

Comment: Where can we find a live example? With just these snippets we are not able to find the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your css is working but maybe WordPress is overriding it. Try putting `!important` next to the name of the font.

Example:

```
#man_translated {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-family: chunkfiveregular !important;
}
```

or you could also use relative links. Instead of putting `http://careerteam.de/wp-content/themes/theme1383/css/chunkfive-webfont.eot`, Get rid of `http://careerteam.de/` and make it like this:

```
url('wp-content/themes/theme1383/css/chunkfive-webfont.eot');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pzMPS/)

Answer (score 1):

Checklist:

- Your FontFace declaration is at the ***very*** top of the stylesheet.
- All font files are uploaded to server and in correct place? Your code as it stands assumes the fonts will be uploaded in the same directory as your stylesheet.
- Your are adding `font-family: 'ChunkFiveRegular;` to every element you want to use the ChunkFive font.

Comment: all checked. Now I use absolute urls just to make sure. They are all right. You can open'em in an external tab.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly use the single quotes ( ' ) in here:

```
font-family: 'ChunkFiveRegular';
```

and in here (also not calling a *.p* class, but a *p* element:

```
p {font-family:'ChunkFiveRegular';}
```

Comment: true, forgot that last single quote, but still not working. The .p just was an example, but true, I should have written p without the class-dot.

Comment: have you added the single quotes on the p value? ( p {font-family:'ChunkFiveRegular';}, witch is not added on your example.

Comment: still not working. wordpress just hates me..
firebug isnt even displaying the font correctly when i hover the attribute like it does with other fonts (those 5 examples sentences)

Comment: Ok. If this is on wordpress, than your css are possible being rejected because of another css. Have you checked styles that the element are respecting to render? Is this live? Can you post a link?

Comment: http://www.careerteam.de/en/
Let me explain: h1,h2,h3.. normally are converted into canvas kinda images instead of text. Now, I translate something via javascript after page load. Since those canvas cant be generated then anymore after initial pageload, I need to add the fontstyle manually.

Comment: What is this: local('ò∫') ? I've been checking some codes of mine that I used @font-face and in none of them this characters appears. Instead, they all have something like: "url('chunkfive-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')," in its place.

Answer (score 0):

On your actual site only the following stylesheets are loaded:
http://www.careerteam.de/wp-content/themes/theme1383/css/normalize.css
http://www.careerteam.de/wp-content/themes/theme1383/style.css
http://www.careerteam.de/wp-content/themes/theme1383/css/prettyPhoto.css
http://www.careerteam.de/wp-content/themes/theme1383/css/grid.css
http://www.careerteam.de/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/styles.css?ver=3.1.1

> My code at top of style.css

does not contain `@font-face {...}`!

So probably you are using the "wrong" CSS file ...?
Or cached version not updated?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably start to simplify your problem by getting rid of all the @font-face declarations except the truetype one, since all major browsers support this mode in their current versions:
http://caniuse.com/ttf

Then you should check the mime types your server exports are right

Then you should try to make sure you always write the font name the same way (with or without quotes)

Answer (score 0):

The paths are most definitely wrong. It needs the path from the folder that this referencing stylesheet is in. Fist of all, within your css folder create a **fonts** folder put the font files there and do this;

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'chunkfiveregular';
src: url('fonts/chunkfive-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/chunkfive-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/chunkfive-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/chunkfive-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/chunkfive-webfont.svg#chunkfiveregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose if you're going to use @font-face or cufon. @font-face code snippet should be in your style.css and your fonts be in their own folder.

Example:

```
Your theme's folder
- /css
-  /font 
- theme files
```

You don't need to have the full URL to your font in your @font-face in your style sheet.

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'chunkfiveregular';
    src: url('font/chunkfive-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/chunkfive-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('font/chunkfive-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('font/chunkfive-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('font/chunkfive-webfont.svg#chunkfiveregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And you have to put the font name in the elements in the design where you want them. This takes looking through your style sheet. And in some cases, if the exact element you are trying to change the font for is not there, check your page source and write in the element. Some themes might look like things are together, but a lot of people forget the generated markup that WordPress does when putting in page IDs, post IDs, widgets, and with HTML5, you are dealing with more tags like article, section, and even aside.